# Orchard CMS Multiple Layouts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

Using Visual Studio 2012, C#, MVC4 and Orchard CMS.

Ok so I have created a new Theme using the orchard.exe like so

```
codegen theme mynewtheme
```

in this theme ive created a new layout, its all up and running fine.

Problem i have is this layout needs to change, or a page needs to use different layouts that i define.

now i looked into this, and theirs a few ways around it, all mainly hacks.  However i did hear that orchard were going to introduce this into the CMS.

As were on 1.7.2 Has this feature been implemented? (switching layouts for different pages), and if so can someone provide a link to the specific Docs?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Downplay.Orchard.LayoutSelector

Can you not use this module from the gallery?

Comment: yeh ive looked at a few different ways to do this, but I did hear that they was going to put it in the actual core.

Comment: Where did you hear this? And is there a problem with using a third party module to achieve this? I doubt it would make it into core because it isn't really a core feature, just extra functionality a select number of people would use.

Comment: heard it from multiple sources whilst looking for a work around, But it appears it isnt in the core, so a 3rd party version or custom built one will have to do , thanks for the info!

Comment: Amusingly, it was in the core a long, long time ago. Works fine as a module though.